# PHP how to go one level up on dirname(__FILE__)

Tags: php, dirname

I have a folder structure as follows:

```
mydomain.example
  ->Folder-A
  ->Folder-B
```

I have a string from Database that is `../Folder-B/image1.jpg`, which points to an image in `Folder-B`.

Inside a script in `Folder-A`, I am using `dirname(__FILE__)` to fetch the filename and I get
`mydomain.example/Folder-A`. Inside this script, I need to get a string that says `'mydomain.example/Folder-B/image1.jpg`. I tried

```
$path=dirname(__FILE__).'/'.'../Folder-B/image1.jpg';
```

This shows up as `mydomain.com%2FFolder-A%2F..%2FFolder-B%2Fimage1.jpg`

This is for a Facebook share button, and this fails to fetch the correct image. Anyone know how to get the path correctly?

I hope to get a URL: `mydomain.example%2FFolder-B%2Fimage1.jpg`

Comment: [This answer by Petah](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094776/php-how-to-go-one-level-up-on-dirname-file#answer-11094813) actually answers the question better than the accepted answer. (It actually tells you how to move up a level, not just how to avoid having to.)

Answer (score 301, accepted):

For PHP < 5.3 use:

```
$upOne = realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/..');
```

In PHP 5.3 to 5.6 use:

```
$upOne = realpath(__DIR__ . '/..');
```

In PHP >= 7.0 use:

```
$upOne = dirname(__DIR__, 1);
```

Comment: The problem is , My target file is saved as ../Folder-B/image1.jpg in the database.
So with your approach as well as mine, I get mydomain.com/Folder-A/../Folder-B/image1.jpg. The share button does not recognize it, though If I copy this to a browser, it seems to fetch the correct image.

Comment: @Petah - I've spent hours on this, then discovered `realpath()` from your post. Resolved my last niggle with the output perfectly, thank you!

Comment: This answer actually answers the question. The accepted answer just provides a workaround to avoid the problem, but does not actually tell us "how to go one level up on dirname(__FILE__)". Well done.

Comment: Alternative way: `dirname(__DIR__)`

Comment: @Nefelim yea, that is mentioned in the other answers.

Answer (score 25):

If you happen to have php 7.0+ you could use levels.

`dirname( __FILE__, 2 )` with the second parameter you can define the amount of levels you want to go back.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php

Answer (score 18):

Try this

```
dirname(dirname( __FILE__ ))
```

Edit: removed "./" because it isn't correct syntax. Without it, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

You could use PHP's dirname function.
`<?php echo dirname(__DIR__); ?>`.
That will give you the name of the parent directory of `__DIR__`, which stores the current directory.

Comment: I tried that, and I can get the url. the problem is, I have a ../ in my target file's name that is saved in the database. I need to get rid of that in the final url.

Comment: Maybe a regular expression, something along the lines of:

/[^\/\\]+\.\.\/?\/

Use that to remove the parent/../ from the path. 'should' work, have not tested however.

Comment: Sorry, I made a slight error in the above regular expression, ?\/ should actually be ?/

Comment: No problem, I figured it was a typo. I did figure out the problem with some additional reading. Thanks for your comments :)

Comment: **Best solution** IMHO

Answer (score 5):

```
dirname(__DIR__,level);
dirname(__DIR__,1);
```

level is how many times will you go back to the folder

Answer (score 1):

You can use `realpath` to remove unnessesary part:

```
// One level up
echo str_replace(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/..'), '', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));

// Two levels etc.
echo str_replace(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../..'), '', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
```

On windows also replace `\` with `/` if need that in URL.

Answer (score 0):

One level up, I have used:

```
str_replace(basename(__DIR__) . '/' . basename(__FILE__), '', realpath(__FILE__)) . '/required.php';
```

or for php < 5.3:

```
str_replace(basename(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/' . basename(__FILE__), '', realpath(__FILE__)) . '/required.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

To Whom, deailing with share hosting environment and still chance to have Current PHP less than 7.0 
Who does not have `dirname( __FILE__, 2 );` it is possible to use following.

```
function dirname_safe($path, $level = 0){
    $dir = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path);
    $level = $level * -1;
    if($level == 0) $level = count($dir);
    array_splice($dir, $level);
    return implode($dir, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
}

print_r(dirname_safe(__DIR__, 2));
```

Answer (score -2):

I use this, if there is an absolute path (this is an example):

```
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Folder-B/image1.jpg");
```

if there is a picture to show, this is enough:

```
echo("<img src='/Folder-B/image1.jpg'>");
```