# php rename (move) from one dir to another that is two levels back

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp, rename

my script file path is:

C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\test\test.php

I need to run code from this path that will move images from path:

C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\uploads\2017\04

to:

C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\uploads\images

My problem is that I have no idea how to force "rename" go two directories back in path.

I was trying something like:

```
$srcPath = realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../..' . '/uploads/2017/04/obrazek.png');
```

error I'm getting atm (I've changed my folder permissions, so maybe it is something with path?):

```
Warning: rename(C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\uploads\2017\04\obrazek.png,C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\uploads\images): access denied
. (code: 5) in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\uploadsdir-manager\test.php on line 16
```

edit rename code:

```
$srcPath = realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../..' . '/uploads/2017/04/obrazek.png');
$destPath = realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../..' . '/uploads/images');
/*$srcDir = opendir($srcPath);*/
echo $srcPath ;

sleep(1); 
rename($srcPath, $destPath);
```

Comment: This question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094776/php-how-to-go-one-level-up-on-dirname-file

Comment: would you show us the code of the `rename` too?

Comment: what did you change the folder's permission to? what user did you give it permission on it ?

Comment: @Motassem MK I've unchecked "read only" from uploads folder, but looks like it didn't save.

Comment: you're moving a file, means you're "modifying" the content of both folders, the source and destination, for instance (not to waste time on diagnosing) give "everyone" full permission on both folders and try it like that

Comment: I'm wondering if you want to share your php_log so we can take a peek =)

Comment: I've added this code before rename: chmod($srcPath, 0755);
chmod($destPath, 0755); but still getting permissions error (even if I uncheck read only manualy and save, it doesn't save).

Comment: @riten is this on a windows or a linux server?

Comment: buddy, try using `copy` instead of `rename`, would it work?

Comment: @unixmiah windows xampp, just learning php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally after many hours.. find out how to fix it so here you go:

```
$srcPath =  (realpath (dirname(__FILE__) . '\..\..' . '\uploads\2017\04') . '\obrazek2.png');
$destPath = (realpath (dirname(__FILE__) . '\..\..' . '\uploads\images') . '\obrazek2.png');

rename ($srcPath , $destPath );
```

The key was adding file name `. '\obrazek2.png'` after dirname (), because if filename is inside dirname () and it is destination path in rename, then it returns empty... :)

Not sure if I'm clear enough, because of my English, but it works and hopes it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're in a Windows machine, so you're using the wrong type of slashes: `/../..' . '/uploads/2017/04/obrazek.png'`

You could try to replace them with backslashes:`\..\..\uploads\2017\04\obrazek.png'`

Or you could try something like this:

```
$path = substr($srcPath, 0, strrpos($srcPath, '\20'));

// $path now contaits: 'C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\uploads';

// Then you can do:

$srcPath = $path . '\images';
```

Regarding the warning error:

```
Warning: rename(C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\uploads\2017\04\obrazek.png,C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\uploads\images): access denied. (code: 5) in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\uploadsdir-manager\test.php on line 16
```

It seems that you try to rename a file to directory, so probably you forgot to append the file name to the new path.

`$srcPath` contains a file. `$destPath` contains a directory, but it should contain the file name.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at it, it looks wrong

```
$srcPath = realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../..' . '/uploads/2017/04/obrazek.png');
```

it should be

```
$srcPath = realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '../..' . '/uploads/2017/04/obrazek.png');
```

You have an extra `/` slash at the beginning.

Comment: I was even getting "Warning: rename(,): Invalid argument" after removing first slash :)