# Wordpress plugin approval standards: ## Calling file locations poorly

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming, wordpress-plugin-creation

I've submitted a widget to Wordpress.org and received this guidance:

> The way your plugin is referencing other files is not going to work
> with all setups of WordPress.
>
> When you hardcode in paths like wp-content or your plugin folder name,
> or assume that everyone has WordPress in the root of their domain, you
> cause anyone using 'Giving WordPress it's own directory' (a VERY
> common setup) to break. In addition, WordPress allows users to change
> the name of wp-content, so you would break anyone who chooses to do
> so.
>
> Please review the following link and update your plugin accordingly.
> And don't worry about supporting WordPress 2.x or lower. We don't
> encourage it nor expect you to do so, so save yourself some time and
> energy.
>
> - https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/determining-plugin-and-content-directories/
>
> Remember to make use of the **FILE** variable, in order than your
> plugin function properly in the real world.
>
> Example(s) from your plugin:

```
my-widget/includes/my-widget-scripts.php:6:
wp_enqueue_style('my-widget-main-style', plugins_url(). '/my-widget/css/style.css');
    
my-widget/includes/my-widget-scripts.php:8:
wp_enqueue_script('my-widget-main-script', plugins_url(). '/my-widget/js/main.js');
```

I've followed the link and tried out some of the variations therein, but nothing has worked to replace the code I currently have (found at the bottom of the quote).

What should I replace it with that will be found up to standards for Wordpress.org?

Comment: What about `__DIR__`? Something like 'wp_enqueue_style('my-widget-main-style', __DIR__ . '/css/style.css');'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for [`plugins_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugins_url/). The first argument takes a `$path` argument to a append to the URL. The second takes a full path to a plugin. if you pass the [`__FILE__` Magic Constant](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) to it, it will be for your current plugin.

You should take advantage of *both* of those arguments:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'my-widget-main-style', plugins_url( '/css/style.css', __FILE__ );
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-widget-main-script', plugins_url( '/js/main.js', __FILE__ );
```

Comment: Looks like this has it searching, but the directory begins in the includes file instead of the plugin's root: localhost:XXXXX/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/includes/css/style.css?ver=5.5.1

Comment: Moved each folder into the includes folder, it worked! How would I be able to properly grab the root directory though, or is that improper in and of itself?

Comment: My apologies, I missed the `/includes` in the line identifiers. Generally the including file is in the root (usually the main plugin file itself). But if that doesn't work for you, you can use the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094776/php-how-to-go-one-level-up-on-dirname-file. `__FILE__` pulls in the current file, the answer there gives your the ability to "go up one directory" from there. You could also define a variable for it in your main plugin file. Either way, just depends on what works best for you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it in mine:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-widget-main-style', plugins_url('/js/main.js', __FILE__) );
```